# Importing ALOHA plume .pas file in ArcGIS Server web API application

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-silverlight-api

I want to import a .pas file (ALOHA plume file) in ArcGIS Server web API application (JavaScript/Silverlight/Flex). Has anyone tried this before?

I am looking for some directions to archive the same.

Comment: How big is the .pas file? Can post a link to one?

Answer (score 1):

I did it sometime ago, but nor for ArcGIS, for Manifold GIS.
Anyway, we had to write some code to transform the pas file into something readable (a associative array of points of lat and lon) and then import those points.

The same thing can be done for ArcGIS Server.

I don't have the code right know, but I'll look later and come with a precise answer

Comment: Thank you Andrei! I am looking for some direction to achive this. If you have the sample code to convert this values in lat/long in any programming language, I would really appreciate if you share that with me.

Comment: I'll look for it in the weekend, it's stored somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Rahul,

I have developed a widget for flex Viewer that parses the .pas file. You can find the widget and code here:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=06e2c33649c34c478a15dace967d0cdd